# Search inside folder, if no files found older than X Days output something

Tags: bash, find

Wondering if someone can help, i seem to be in abit of a pickle,
I have a separate program responsible for zipping up data and uploading it to a set folder.
Each Client Site has its own Folder.

I have a bash script to search these folders and delete any files older than 7 days when there is a file count of 7 (I do not want to delete backups if the backup program is not running for example a PC dies and i am unaware of it)

But i would also like to be able to set a trigger that if no files are found older than 2 days, Then to trigger an event, I am struggling to do this part.

Here is an example of my code:

```
for dir in $(find /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXXX.co.uk/Backups/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d); do              # iterate over the directories
    files=$(ls --ignore='.*' $dir | egrep '\.Zip$' | wc -l)              # array of files in that directory
    if (( $files  > 6 )); then                          #If filecount 7 then delete some backups 
        echo $dir "Directory has "$files " files"
        find $dir -mtime +7 -type f -delete             #add -delete to delete the files
        echo "Deleted Files older than 7 days old" 
    elif [[ -n "find $dir -mtime -2" ]]; then        # Check if no uploads been present for more than 48 hours, if so trigger warning
       echo $dir "Has not backed up for 2 days - trigger email" 
    fi
done
```

The Backup Folder Structure is as follow:

- Backups/ClientName/20220217.Zip
- Backups/ClientName/20220218.Zip

If client has multiple sites.

- Backups/ClientName/Sitename2/20220218.Zip
- Backups/ClientName/Sitename2/20220217.Zip
- Backups/ClientName/Sitename1/20220218.Zip
- Backups/ClientName/Sitename1/20220217.Zip

The code is basically duplicated twice using `-mindepth 2 -maxdepth 3` to overcome the directory change.

All i am wanting to do is echo out the directory structure of the folder than has no backups in 48 hours.
From here i can write a trigger to send a email alert.

Answer (score 0):

`[[ -n "find $dir -mtime -2" ]]` always evaluate as true because you are not running find, you are testing the string `"find $dir -mtime -2"` for emptiness. Run `find` and test the result:

```sh
res=$(find "$dir" -mtime -2)
if [[ -n "$res" ]]; then
```

Note:

```
files=$(ls --ignore='.*' $dir | egrep '\.Zip$' | wc -l)
```

is terrible. You should probably prefer something like:

```
files=("$dir"/*.Zip)
if (( ${#files[@]}  > 6 )); then
```

That is, use the regular bash pathname expansion (`"$dir"/*.Zip`) to store the paths of all files of interest in bash array `files`, and then use the number of elements in the array (`${#files[@]}`).